# Can the Entry Permit No of two visas be the same?

Tags: visas, paperwork, uae

Can the Entry Permit No and/or U.I.D No of two different Work Visas (UAE) be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know about Dubai, but Qatar ID Number is of 11 digits.

- First digit will be 2, if you are born in 20th Century i.e. on or before 2000. 3 if you are born after.
- 2nd & 3rd digit is your birth year in yy format.
- 4th, 5th, 6th digit is your nationality code, same for same country.
  Last five is your sequence number of entering country first time, with somebody entering at 01 Jan 00:01 will be 00001.

So, no, two work visa numbers for two different persons will not be same. Although same person re-entering Qatar after getting first visa cancelled will get same number as earlier.

Note that this applies to Qatar ID Numbers. The temporary visa you need to enter and get the RP process completed may be totally different.